# regex to match a string with mixed capital letters and \n

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a regex which will match a string only if it starts with an \n, continues with at least one capital letter and ends with an \n. The string could contain repetitions of this pattern, for example:

\n[A-Z]\n[A-Z]\n.

I've tried this regular expression: \n(([A-Z]+\n)+), on this input:

> 200LA 012F5421F2E8A172 164 XRAY  1.950  0.176 NA no Endolysin  [Enterobacteria phage T4] ||1C63A 1C64A 1C65A
>   MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILR
>   NAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMAQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDA
>   YKNL

I expected to get this result:
('MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMAQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL')

but instead, I got this one:
('MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILR\nNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMAQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDA\nYKNL\n', 'YKNL\n')

Does anybody know what went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why you expected the first result as I can't see a way to get that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex matches the (longest possible version of the) first section that matches your condition.

The first line in your text doesn't start with an `\n` so it moves to look at the line right after the first `\n`, and since it matches the condition, the groups specified by your regex are accepted as a result.

For your result, I would suggest matching with `\n(?:[A-Z]+\n)+` (`?:` stands for non-capturing group to prevent capturing of none but the last group), then replaceing newlines with empty strings:

```
>>> a = """>200LA 012F5421F2E8A172 164 XRAY  1.950  0.176 NA no Endolysin <ENLYS_BPT4(1-164)> [Enterobacteria phage T4] ||1C63A 1C64A 1C65A
... MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILR
... NAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMAQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDA
... YKNL
... """
>>> m = re.findall('\n(?:[A-Z]+\n)+', a)
>>> m[0].replace('\n', '')
'MNIFEMLRIDEGLRLKIYKDTEGYYTIGIGHLLTKSPSLNAAKSELDKAIGRNTNGVITKDEAEKLFNQDVDAAVRGILRNAKLKPVYDSLDAVRRAALINMVFQMGETGVAGFTNSLRMAQQKRWDEAAVNLAKSRWYNQTPNRAKRVITTFRTGTWDAYKNL'
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!